# Postgres procedure not updating selected row

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I'm working on a Django application that uses Stored Procedures on a PostgreSQL database.

I'm stuck in a very strange (for me, at least) problem.

I have the following SP code:

```
create procedure inbound_550(p_operation_id integer)
    language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
                                                            
    file_operation record;

    ...
            
begin
            

    select
        oo.id,
        oo.file_id,
        ot.transaction_type_id,
        ot.code 
    into
        file_operation
    from
        operations_operation oo
    join
        operations_type ot on ot.id = oo.type_id
    where
        oo.id = p_operation_id;

    for line in
            
        # select some records from other tables using parameter p_operation_id on some FKs
            
    loop
    
        # business logic here with some calculations and some inserts
        sum_tax_day = X # some value
            
    end loop;

    operation_avg_year_tax = ((1 + (sum_tax_day / 100)) ^ 252) - 1;
    update operations_operation set avg_year_tax = operation_avg_year_tax where id = p_operation_id;

end
$$;
```

The problem is, when I call this procedure from the console it runs fine and the field `avg_year_tax` gets updated with the `operation_avg_year_tax` value but, when I call the procedure from my application using Python and psycopg2 the field is not updated, it seems that the `update` statement is ignored.

Here is the Python code used to call the procedure:

```
from django.db import connection


class Inbound:

    def __init__(self, operation):

        self.operation = operation

    def main(self):

        conn = connection
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('call inbound_550({});'.format(self.operation.id))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

I've tried setting the `autocommit` both `True` and `False` but still no update.

Any ideas? Been stuck in this for a couple of days already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working on the same database in the console and from the Django code? Have you looked at the Postgres log to see what is happening? Does the `operation.id` exist in the database?

Comment: HI @AdrianKlaver thanks for your questions. Yes, the database is the same, actually it's the only one in the server. The log just says the time it took to run the SP and no errors.

Comment: What happens if you run this using psycopg2 outside Django?

Comment: Same results as if I ran inside Django, no update! If I call the SP from the PSQL console or from the Pycharm DB console it runs fine. I was thinking about some isolation level problem but I have no knowledge about it yet to tell.

Comment: Have you tried [callproc](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=call#cursor.callproc)?

Comment: Yes, Postgres says I can't call a Stored Procedure using ```callproc``` it must be ```call```

Comment: Hmm, just tried callproc and got same result. That is misnamed. I'm going to have to think about this.

Comment: I could not replicate with a simple SP. FYI, I would use `cursor.execute('call inbound_550(%s);', [self.operation.id])` as safer parameter passing.  At this point I would add some `RAISE NOTICE` 's in code to make sure what is happening is what you think is happening. In particular the value of `p_operation_id`